# Simfony2 Service within a Service Attempted to call method "get"

Tags: symfony, authentication, service, dependency-injection, access-token

I wanted to set a service to get the user logged in. This service is used in another service that uses the username to set it as the Author of comments. The problem I have is that I cannot inicialize the getloggedUSer function because of the get statement. The security.context has been updated in Symfony2.6 and I wanted to use it as suggested here http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

The error I get:

```
Attempted to call method "get" on class "Usuarios\UsersBundle\Services\UserManager".
```

Did you mean to call "getloggedUser"?

The UserManager Service that holds the function I want to use:

```
namespace Usuarios\UsersBundle\Services;
/**
 * Class UserManager
 */
class UserManager
{
private $em;


/**
 * @param EntityManager $em
 *
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getloggedUser()
{
    ###Failing Line
    $loggedUser = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    return $loggedUser;
}
```

The PostManager Service that calls the getloggedUser function:

```
namespace Blog\BlogBundle\Services;
/**
* Class PostManager
*/
class PostManager
{
private $em;
private $formFactory;
private $um;

/**
 * @param EntityManager $em
 * @param formFactoryInterface $formFactory
 * @param UserManager $um
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManager $um)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->um = $um;
}
/**
 * Create and validate a new comment
 *
 * @param Post    $post
 * @param Request $request
 * @return FormInterface|boolean
 */
public function createComment (Post $post, Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setPost($post);                     
    $comment->setAuthorName($this->um->getloggedUser());### Failing Line

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(new CommentType(), $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->em->persist($comment);
        $this->em->flush();
    return true;
}
return $form;
}
```

The "get" is not usable in this situation apparently. The ### notations are not present in the actual code and are intended for reference here. What is wrong in my code declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `UserManager` service is defined wrong. You cannot use method `get` as you're trying - this is habit taken from `Controller` class which provides `get` method.

What you need to do is change definition of your `UserManager` service so you inject `TokenStorage` to your class.

**services.yml**

```
services:
    your.user.manager.service:
        class: Usuarios\UsersBundle\Services\UserManager
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @security.token_storage]
```

**UserManager**:

```
class UserManager
{


    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }


    public function getloggedUser()
    {
        $loggedUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        return $loggedUser;
    }
}
```